# Image not showing in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm currently trying to iterate over my entries and display the image from each of them. The image url is stored as a string in the database.

```
<% @feed.entries.each do |image| %>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <%= image_tag(image) %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

When using this, unfortunately this comes up within the image src

```
/images/#<Entry:0x007fcf40144210>
```

Not too sure what this is doing.

**EDIT**

```
#<Entry id: 1, title: nil, image: "http://40.media.tumblr.com/889c65a662a1b690f299593...", source: nil, created_at: "2016-04-11 11:31:00", updated_at: "2016-04-11 11:31:00", feed_id: 1>, #<Entry id: 2, title: nil, image: "http://41.media.tumblr.com/3cfd8c9c93870fa716356bc...", source: nil, created_at: "2016-04-11 11:31:00", updated_at: "2016-04-11 11:31:00", feed_id: 1>, #<Entry id: 3, title: nil, image: "http://40.media.tumblr.com/7906907023dd04ff5c4be15...", source: nil, created_at: "2016-04-11 11:31:00", updated_at: "2016-04-11 11:31:00", feed_id: 1>, #<Entry id: 4, title: nil, image: "http://49.media.tumblr.com/3405440b713440ba490f473...", source: nil, created_at: "2016-04-11 11:31:00", updated_at: "2016-04-11 11:31:00", feed_id: 1>, #<Entry id: 5, title: nil, image: "http://45.media.tumblr.com/9185ff46269e01bd6d7827e...", source: nil, created_at: "2016-04-11 11:31:00", updated_at: "2016-04-11 11:31:00", feed_id: 1>, #<Entry id: 6, title: nil, image: "http://41.media.tumblr.com/e1d5e279df2b765c901c9fa...", source: nil, created_at: "2016-04-11 11:31:00", updated_at: "2016-04-11 11:31:00", feed_id: 1>, #<Entry id: 7, title: nil, image: "http://41.media.tumblr.com/061ab14be3316e82b1ea67e...", source: nil, created_at: "2016-04-11 11:31:00", updated_at: "2016-04-11 11:31:00", feed_id: 1>, #<Entry id: 8, title: nil, image: "http://41.media.tumblr.com/975c58b368d20d6f54f3eed...", source: nil, created_at: "2016-04-11 11:31:00", updated_at: "2016-04-11 11:31:00", feed_id: 1>, #<Entry id: 9, title: nil, image: "http://49.media.tumblr.com/65e811cefd6ec3235d933a0...", source: nil, created_at: "2016-04-11 11:31:00", updated_at: "2016-04-11 11:31:00", feed_id: 1>, #<Entry id: 10, title: nil, image: "http://41.media.tumblr.com/b2486d84cc2c30bbdb50b0b...", source: nil, created_at: "2016-04-11 11:31:00", updated_at: "2016-04-11 11:31:00", feed_id: 1>, ...]>
```

Comment: `<%= image_tag(image.url) %>` - try this , how you are storing images ?

Comment: Doesn't work. undefined method `url' for #<Entry:0x007fcf445dda98>

Comment: `<%= image_tag(image.image.url) %>` -can you give it a try

Comment: Nope undefined method `url' for #<String:0x007fcf409627d0>. I've added the rails console and what it returns

Comment: `<%= image_tag(image.image) %>` - does this works ?

Comment: Yes. works - could you please explain within an answer how that works and why it worked for other people and myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating through `entries`, so ideally your iterator variable should be named as `entry` instead of `image` which makes the confusion here. And, every `entry` has an image,  so it should look like the followings:

```
<% @feed.entries.each do |entry| %>
  <div class="grid-item">
   <%= image_tag(entry.image) %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Hope it makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

`@feed.entries` is evidently not an array of image urls.

It seems that `Entry` is an object. Ostensibly one of it's columns is the url.

Is there an `entry.url` or `entry.image_url`. column?

In which case you could use `@feed.entries.pluck(:image).each` to operate over an array of urls.

Comment: I've added the rails console to the question

Comment: @Jonathan glad you figured it out.